# Jackson: Serialize the same object into multiple JSONs

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have two POJOs that look like:

```java
public ResponseA {
  private HeavyObject object;
  private AdditionalDataA additionalData;

  public ResponseA(HeavyObject object, AdditionalDataA additionalData) {
    this.object = object;
    this.additionalData = additionalData;
  }
}
```

```java
public ResponseB {
  private HeavyObject object;
  private AdditionalDataB additionalData;

  public ResponseB(HeavyObject object, AdditionalDataB additionalData) {
    this.object = object;
    this.additionalData = additionalData;
  }
}
```

and then I have a method that sends these objects to different endpoints, something like:

```java
  public void sendResponses(
      ObjectMapper mapper, 
      HeavyObject object, 
      AdditionalDataA addDataA, 
      AdditionalDataB addDataB) {

    // Here object is serialized twice, which is costly!
    String jsonA = mapper.writeValueAsString(new ResponseA(object, addDataA));
    String jsonB = mapper.writeValueAsString(new ResponseB(object, addDataB));
    sendResponseA(jsonA);
    sendResponseB(jsonB);
}
```

Is there a way I could serialize these responses so that the `HeavyObject` is serialized only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can annotate the `object` field in `ResponseA` and `ResponseB` with `@JsonRawValue`, convert it to a `String`,  and serialize it in a separate step.